# @Cacheable not working with redis

Tags: spring, caching, redis

I have the following method I want to cache for a period of time:

```
@Cacheable("companySegment")
  public Map<String, CompanySegmentItemModel> getCompanySegment() {
    Map<String, String> responseMap = null;
    responseMap = apiRequest(ClientConnectUtil.CLIENT_COMPANY_SEGMENT_GET_PATH,
            RequestMethod.GET.name(), null);
    CompanySegmentModel companySegment = JsonHelper.jsonStringToObject(responseMap.get(DiceHTTPClient.ENTITY), CompanySegmentModel.class);
    for (CompanySegmentItemModel companySegmentItem : companySegment.getUserGroups()) {
      companySegmentMap.put(companySegmentItem.getGroup_id(), companySegmentItem);
    }

    return companySegmentMap;

  }
```

However when running this on my local the method call never gets cached. No matter how many times I hit the method:

```
$ redis-cli keys "companySegment"
(empty list or set)
$ redis-cli keys "companySegment"
(empty list or set)
$ redis-cli keys "companySegment"
(empty list or set)
$ redis-cli keys "companySegment"
(empty list or set)
```

Simple enough use case but not entering the data cache setup seems fine as I can see all my hibernate cache keys.